# Is it possible to store a word that a user inputs as an array of characters?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, character, ascii

I'm working on a program that encodes a sentence into a binary file by converting each individual character of the user's input into binary numeric value used to represent that character in ASCII. I can't seem to think of a better way to convert the string into that so I want to know if I can store a user input as an array of characters. For example if the user enters the world "Apple" is it possible to store each individual letter as a character?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that after I convert the word in binary numeric value 1010101 etc.. I have to put the binary numeric value into a random string of 0's and 1's and display it to the screen.

Comment: Sounds like you just want to index the string.

Comment: Won't `std::string` or `char[]` work?

Comment: What have you done so far? What's not working?

Comment: well, I haven't started acctually coding. I'm trying to do my pseudo code right now and this is the part I'm stuck on.

Comment: @user2419691, I mean that if you have `std::string str("abc");`, `str[0]` gives you `'a'` and likewise.

Comment: The letters are *already* stored as binary numeric values, called *characters*.  This is what `char` stores.  A string is made up of a bunch of these, which is essentially an *array*.  When you write these to a file, you have stored the array.  Either you don't understand how data works, or I don't understand your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  Your question is puzzling.  If you read a line of data into a string, there is somewhere lurking an array of `char` each containing (one byte of) one character, so that 'A' is held as a binary value in the zeroth element.  So, it is completely automatic.

Comment: @paddy it might a bit of both. I have edited my question I hope that can clear some things up a bit.

Comment: @chris If i were to have strings that were different in length such as apple or pineapple, would I use a for loop to get the program to recognize the difference in length so it can convert the individual characters into ascii -> binary for any variable length of a string?

Comment: @user2419691, There's a `length` member function. You'd probably be better off with a standard library algorithm, though.

Comment: What do you mean by "put the binary numeric value into a random string of 0's and 1's"? Are you actually randomizing the bits once they've been encoded from the ASCII?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an old answer of mine, dealing with converting integers to binary: [How to manipulate and represent binary numbers in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714148/how-to-manipulate-and-represent-binary-numbers-in-c/11714207#11714207)

Most often, people write loops to create these strings one bit at a time, but it's a bit pointless (apart from being an exercise in bitwise operations).  If you adapt my answer above to single chars, you can do it compactly by hand using a lookup table that represents half a byte:

```
std::string StringToBinary( const string & s )
{
    static const char lookup[16][5] = {
        "0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", 0100", "0101", "0110", "0111",
        "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011", 1100", "1101", "1110", "1111"
    };

    std::string bin;
    bin.reserve(s.size()*8);

    for( i = 0; i < s.size(); i++ ) {
        bin.append( lookup[(unsigned char)s[i] >> 4],   4);
        bin.append( lookup[(unsigned char)s[i] & 0x0f], 4);
    }
    return bin;
}
```

This takes the high-order nybble and (`s[i]>>4`) and the low-order nybble (`s[i]&0x0f`) and converts each to a 4-bit string.  If you want, you could use an 8-bit lookup table, but you'd want to write a small program to generate the code (or generate it dynamically).

The above solution is easier, without involving lots of bitwise operations.